# Как сделать редирект на страницах с пагинацией?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, допустим на странице рубрик или категорий товаров есть пагинация, и по определённому событию нужно сделать редирект со страницы допустим /page/2 на первую страницу данной рубрики (категории).
Допустим если есть определённая переменная в $_POST, тогда нужно сделать редирект на 1ю страницу категории.
Как это сделать?

```
wp_redirect(?); // чту нужно указывать в wp_redirect  ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте код в `function.php`

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $page = substr($path, 0, -1);

    if ($page == "") return; // do not redirect from home page

    if ($page == '/product-category/computers-laptops/page/2/') {
        if ( isset($_POST['var']) ) {
            $var = $_POST['var'];
            if ($var === '2') {
                wp_redirect( '/page/2/' , 301 );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Хук `template_redirect` предназначен, собственно, для редиректа и срабатывает в нужное время в WordPress. В примере определяется адрес текущей страницы (`$page`) и переменная из `POST`. При соблюдении условий осуществляется редирект.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55669/discussion-on-answer-by-kagg-design-------).